# PHP - float number accuracy difference on WAMP and a web server

Tags: php, wamp, floating-accuracy

I am aware that php float numbers [are not accurate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and I know solutions like [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php). I tested the following code on local `WAMP server` and another server (that uses `Nginx`):

```
$size = 0.0006;
$data = json_encode( array("size" => $size));
var_dump($data);
```

The output on WAMP:

```
string '{"size":0.0006}' (length=15)
```

The output on the other server:

```
string(31) "{"size":0.00059999999999999995}"
```

PHP version on both servers is `7.3`. Why am I getting the expected result on WAMP and something messed up on my hosting server? Is there any configuration that I can fix?

Comment: as mention here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php never trust floating number results to the last digit.

Comment: Round the values to number of decimal position you need for your site using number_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WAMPs output is not produced by PHP itself but by the [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) third-party extension. [More specifically](https://xdebug.org/docs/display):

> Xdebug replaces PHP's var_dump() function for displaying variables.
> Xdebug's version includes different colors for different types and
> places limits on the amount of array elements/object properties,
> maximum depth and string lengths.

Apart from that, the precision of implicit string casting of floating values is [configurable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision):

```
$size = 0.0006;
var_dump($size);
ini_set('precision', 18);
var_dump($size);
```

```
float(0.0006)
float(0.000599999999999999947)
```

In the case of `json_encode()` the casting is explicit and we can read in the [manual](https://php.net/json_encode):

> The encoding is affected by the supplied options and additionally the encoding of float values depends on the value of [serialize_precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.serialize-precision).

```
$size = 0.0006;
echo json_encode( array("size" => $size)), PHP_EOL;
ini_set('serialize_precision', 18);
echo json_encode( array("size" => $size)), PHP_EOL;
```

```
{"size":0.0006}
{"size":0.000599999999999999947}
```

Comment: This extension explains the difference in output formatting but not the numerical content. I disabled it and the formatting changed but the value was still correct

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Have you verified the precision set in both systems?

Comment: Your answer gave me the clue to search for "precision" in phpinfo() and I found the difference between servers. In my case this is the solution: ini_set('serialize_precision', -1);

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant. I've hopefully fixed my answer.