# PHP http_build_query loss of float precision

Tags: php, http, curl

As the title says, when I place an array into `http_build_query()` all the float types end up with lost precision. For instance:

```
$arr = ['test' => 22854.94878205978 ];
print_r($arr);                   // prints 22854.94878205978
print_r(http_build_query($arr)); // prints 22854.94878206
```

I'm unsure why. I can't find anything in the PHP docs that would cause this. My main focus is just sending some data via a POST request using cURL via PHP, ie.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arr));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Since I need the precision, what can I do and why is this happening?

Comment: _"Since I need the precision, what can I do"_... use strings

Comment: Or explicitly set the precision in your system?

Comment: @mickmackusa what is the variable for that? maybe my googling skills aren't up to par but I haven't found somewhere where I can explicitly set precision?

Comment: What happens if you `ini_set()`? Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996915/2943403  Any change?  If not, just cast your float as a string as Phil suggests.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for this. I've tried it, but ended up with a new problem. Garbage values end up being inserted: ie. `22854.94878205977800004084`

Comment: Well then we are back to that age-old song "[Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/2943403)"

Comment: Looks like @Phil was right then. Computers are lame.

Comment: Related bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49023

Comment: Try with and without the precision declaration: https://3v4l.org/avdgB

Answer (score 0):

You have three options

- Use string to hold float number.
- Set more precision via `ini_set('precision', <precision>);`.
- And you can split float into two integer parts.

Be aware, that floats  (and integer, but they just have max in  min values) are not capable of holding very small numbers (after a dot; take a look at IEEE 754 standard) without loss of precision.

> [The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of approximately 1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

> why is this happening

PHP uses `precision` ini-setting for determining wanted number of digits in a float.